# word for killing a criminal unlawfully by the people?

Tags: word-request

Word request for killing a criminal by a group of people who are outside of the law, who took the law in their own hands and killed a criminal unlawfully??

Comment: Can you explain why "murder" is not appropriate, given that nobody is "outside the law"?

Comment: there is a definite word for this, I just can't remember it

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is *vigilante*. They are volunteers who seek justice, fight and punish (but not necessarily kill) criminals.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko - isn't a vigilante a person who does this kind of thing? I thought the OP wanted a word for the act. I wonder if 'extra-judicial killing' might serve, although even in the complete absence of an operating legal system with jurisdiction, I still say 'murder' has moral implications and could apply.

Comment: Or, of course, there is 'lynching'.

Comment: yes lynching lmao, I couldn't remember this word, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

"Murder" would be the most common word, though I think the word you are trying to remember is "lynch".

Take care using this word, it has a particular connotation in American culture, due to the [lynching of black people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynching_in_the_United_States) who were accused various things, but really as a form of terrorism to preserve racial dominance. Many victims of lynchings were not criminals.